# Creating/saving Loopback model programmatically

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to use

```
// item is some string representing model name

const Model = app.models[item];

Model.create([array of model data],{options}, function(a, b, c){


});
```

but this API is giving me hell, it seems to fire the callback inconsistently if at all, and also, {a,b,c}, seem to be totally inconsistent, in other words, Model.create does not seem to fire a standard error first callback and I simply cannot figure out what it is passing back, seems to be very inconsisent.

I filed an issue on Github for Loopback on this, but I am wondering if there is a better API for programmatically creating models like this.

I am trying to seed our test database with data.

Comment: I read [the PersistedModel.create API docs](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-create) differently. I would think you do `Model.create(arrayOfModelDataObjects, callback)`. I don't see an `options` 2nd param in the official API docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no second [optional parameter](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-create).

```
Model.create({propA: value /*, etc */}, function(err, results){

});
```